# Delete All number or letters

Tags: command, notepad, emeditor

**I got lines like this.**

```
Matt:karolina1

Datt:hdahdahgda

Patt:leonleon1

Ratt:153513513
```

I would like delete everything if after ":" are only numbers or letters
So after this good results should looks :

```
Patt:leonleon1

Matt:karolina1
```

I had command on notepad++ and works very well but i dont know why on emeditor doesnt.

```
.*:([[:alpha:]]+|[[:digit:]]+|[@#$%^*!@]+)\R
```

Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

`\R` should be replaced with `$` in EmEditor. Some literals in [] should be escaped by a backslash, and a duplicate `@` can be removed. Please use `.*:([[:alpha:]]+|[[:digit:]]+|[@#\$%\^\*\!]+)$` instead.